Confusion about series
Hi I have this series $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$$ and when I try to use partial fraction I get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{2(k+2)}\right)$$
Now what do I do?How do I get from this 3 fractions to this fraction
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)$$
I\m new to precalculus and I can't understand these concepts.I'm in highschool and my textbook didn't helped me a lot.
I did understand partial fractions but I have no idea how to apply the 2nd sum to achieve the 3rd sum.

I can see an addition of $0=\frac{1}{2(k+2)}-\frac{1}{2(k+2)}$ to what you've obtained via partial fractions. Not sure why you need to do that unless you have to obtain that specific form.
